# Identifying start-end in a time use data

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with time-use data and want to calculate the duration of a started measurement at each step per id. I was considering using the colsum function, but I am not sure how to handle if an id an activity is fragmented and has multiple starting times.

[image]

Example of output for id `1` and `10`

```
 id start-end   duration
  1 04:00-06:20 15
 10 04:00-4:10   2
 10 04:50-06:20 10
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14), `04:00` = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11), `04:10` = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `04:20` = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `04:30` = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `04:40` = c(11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `04:50` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:00` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:10` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:20` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:30` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:40` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:50` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `06:00` = c(11, 
0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `06:10` = c(11, 
0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `06:20` = c(11, 
0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `06:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `06:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `06:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What does the 11 mean in  the cell?  The sample data your provided are different than the ones in the picture, what is the intended output for the sample data provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `df` is the provided dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
  mutate(id_interval = value == 0,
         id_interval = cumsum(id_interval) + id) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>% 
  group_by(id_interval) %>%
  summarise(
    id = unique(id),
    `start-end` = str_c(head(name, 1), tail(name, 1), sep = "-"),
    duration = n()) %>% 
  select(-id_interval)
```

This yields

```r
# A tibble: 14 × 3
      id `start-end` duration
   <dbl> <chr>          <int>
 1     1 04:00-06:20       15
 2     2 04:00-05:50       12
 3     3 04:00-06:20       15
 4     4 04:00-06:20       15
 5     5 04:00-06:20       15
 6     6 04:00-06:20       15
 7     7 04:00-06:20       15
 8     8 04:00-05:50       12
 9     9 04:00-05:50       12
10    10 04:00-06:20       15
11    11 04:00-06:20       15
12    12 04:00-06:20       15
13    13 04:00-06:20       15
14    14 04:00-06:20       15
```

Note that the provided `dput` input does not correspond to the image above.
It looks more like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**solution using data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

# your sample data does not illustrate it well like on your screenshot
# add some "breaks" on second row, col 4-6
dt[2,4:6] <- 0

dl <- melt(dt, id.vars = "id")
setorder(dl, id, variable)
dl[, .(`start-end` = paste0(first(variable), "-", last(variable)), duration = .N), by = .(id, rleid(value), value > 0)][value == T, .(id, `start-end`, duration)]
```

**output**

```
#     id   start-end duration
#  1:  1 04:00-06:20       15
#  2:  2 04:00-04:10        2
#  3:  2 04:50-05:50        7
#  4:  3 04:00-06:20       15
#  5:  4 04:00-06:20       15
#  6:  5 04:00-06:20       15
#  7:  6 04:00-06:20       15
#  8:  7 04:00-06:20       15
#  9:  8 04:00-05:50       12
# 10:  9 04:00-05:50       12
# 11: 10 04:00-06:20       15
# 12: 11 04:00-06:20       15
# 13: 12 04:00-06:20       15
# 14: 13 04:00-06:20       15
# 15: 14 04:00-06:20       15
```

**data**

```
dt <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14), `04:00` = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11), `04:10` = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `04:20` = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `04:30` = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `04:40` = c(11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `04:50` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:00` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:10` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:20` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:30` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:40` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `05:50` = c(11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `06:00` = c(11, 
0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `06:10` = c(11, 
0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), `06:20` = c(11, 
0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `04:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `05:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `06:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `06:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `06:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```